# Mongo DB (node js) group by dates and sum values of unique ids

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following documents in my collection:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5b8fed64b77d7829788ebdc8"),
  "valueId": "6e01c881-c15e-b754-43bd-0fe7381cc02a",
  "value": 14,
  "date": "2018-09-05T14:51:11.427Z"
}
```

I want to group the "date" by a certain interval, get for all "valueId" a sum of the "value", which is inside the date interval. My current aggregation looks like this:

```
myCollection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            date: {
                $gte: start,
                $lte: end,
            },
        },
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                $toDate: {
                    $subtract: [{ $toLong: '$date' }, { $mod: [{ $toLong: '$date' }, interval] }],
                },
            },
            valueId: { $addToSet: '$valueId' },
        },
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            valueId: 1,
        },
    },
]);
```

Which gives out something like this:

```
{
  _id: 2018-09-04T15:45:00.000Z,
  valueId:[
    'cb255343-9c16-f495-9c29-3697d6c7d6cb',
    '97e729aa-7b0f-c107-d591-01188b768a7a'
  ]
}
```

How can I get it to something like this (simplified with one value):

```
{
  _id: 2018-09-04T15:45:00.000Z,
  valueId: [[
    'cb255343-9c16-f495-9c29-3697d6c7d6cb',
    <sum of value>
  ]]
}
```

EDIT:
Endsolution:

```
myCollection.aggregate([
  {"$match":{"date":{"$gte":start,"$lte":end}}},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":{
      "interval":{"$toDate":{"$subtract":[{"$toLong":"$date"},{"$mod":[{"$toLong":"$date"},interval]}]}},
      "valueId":"$valueId"
    },
    "value":{"$sum":"$value"}
  }},
  { $group: {
        _id: "$_id.interval",
        values: {
           $addToSet: { id: "$_id.valueId", sum: "$value" },}
            }}])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiple group, one for summing value for each valueid and interval combination and second group to push all the documents for interval.

```
myCollection.aggregate([
  {"$match":{"date":{"$gte":start,"$lte":end}}},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":{
      "interval":{"$toDate":{"$subtract":[{"$toLong":"$date"},{"$mod":[{"$toLong":"$date"},interval]}]}},
      "valueId":"$valueId"
    },
    "value":{"$sum":"$value"}
  }},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":"$_id.interval",
    "valueId":{"$push":{"id":"$_id.valueId","sum":"$value"}}
  }}
])
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I understand, what you want to do, but the second group didn´t work. Therefore I changed it a little bit (put it in my original post). But you pushed me in the right direction :)

Comment: Yw. Oh my apologies missed the push modifier. Updated now.